# How do I keep line breaks in an ANSI import to be written to an Outlook Appointment file in RTF?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, appointment

I'm reading the ANSI file (stored in the C drive) and appending the text to the end of an Outlook Appointment item in Rich Text Format.

My code runs how I'm intending it to for the Outlook Appointment file update in RTF, except it doesn't include the original line breaks in the imported ANSI file (ssm_file below). The file path is dictated by dropdown menus in the Excel doc (values imported into custArray). Does anyone have any tips to grab those line breaks from ssm_file? Here's the excerpt of my code for this part:

```
' Add in the service-specific message
    Dim ssm_file As String 'File path to the Site Checks
    Dim ssmtxt As String 'Text in this file
    Dim txtline4 As String
    ssm_file = "C:\Service Organizer\Service Files\" & custArray(index, 2) & " " & custArray(index, 3) & "\service_message.txt"
    Debug.Print ssm_file
    'Read the service-specific message file
    Open ssm_file For Input As #4
    Do Until EOF(4)
        Line Input #4, txtline4
        ssmtxt = ssmtxt & txtline4
    Loop
    msgtxt = msgtxt & ssmtxt & vbNewLine
    Close #4
    doc.Range.InsertBefore msgtxt
```